# Regex to search single field for less than values and string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This is probably a lot less complicated than it seems right now, but looking for help. I am trying to write a regex to search a single field in a MySQL DB.

Basically: It should work like this - if you search for:

```
*Term  =  Result*   
250 Cattle =  anything less than or equal to 250 "Cattle"   
235 Sheep  =  anything less than or equal to 235 "Sheep"
```

The values in the DB look exactly like the term being searched (i.e. "250 Cattle, 300 Horses" would be considered 1 entry)

So it needs to do an operation on a # (i.e <= 250) and be able to specify the category. "Sheep", "Cattle", etc all in the same regex or two conditional regex's. But I haven't figured it out yet. Any help would be amazing.

Comment: the problem is with your db design "250 Cattle, 300 Horses" should be 4 fields not 1

Comment: EDIT: I did not pay close enough attention to the question...You're storing values in your DB in a terrible way. I completely agree with @Dragon. Original_Comment: How come you're not just doing this in your query? pseudoSQL: "Select * FROM animalTable where Animal like :animalType and count <= :animalCount".

Comment: Ok, so... trust me - the DB design for this particular piece was inherited from a crappier older system. If I had the budget from the client to change it, it would be changed. Im reaching out to see if there is any method I could use aside from re-writing the table. I go over budget if not.

Comment: Ok, Still looking. I cannot modify this table - I need to find a range   and a string. So - if someone search 200 beef it should find 0-200 [[:<:]]beef[[:>:]]. Any thoughts on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use regex for this ??

Could'nt you just put every thing in an array (depending on your programming language) or list like so:

Key:250 value:Cattle
Key:300 value:Horse

and then use the reference on the key to compare each other with a loop trought the array/list?

Comparing numbers is way more easy with `if` then with Regex.